# Changing reference scale of annotation feature class in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class, annotation

I've looked all around, but can't find a way to change the reference scale of the Annotation FC in ArcGIS Pro.

Is there a way to do it instead of having to create many FCs?

Answer (score 2):

Changing reference scale for an annotation FC can be a pain. Have you considered re-creating the annotation feature class at the various scales that you might need, and then setting different visible scale ranges for each?

Comment: Unless OP goes with dynamic labels, this is the way.  BTW, not all labelling / annotation functionality has yet been added to Pro making ArcMap still the better and faster tool for this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Annotation Reference Scale by running the geoprocessing tool "Update Annotation Reference Scale (Cartography)"